# uninstalling a self built app, which was created in two copies accidentally

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I built an app through android studio but two copies were created and I could uninstall one copy but the other says that the app is not present in the list of installed apps, but the icon remains.. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the folder of apps from your computer by plugging it in via usb, and then delete all folders from that app there?